# Is Ask Ubuntu the place for tutorials?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I managed to realize something interesting, tricky and not foundable with a simple web search.

Should I post it on Ask Ubuntu, with me asking a question and answering it myself right after?

Comment: You should. However if you get a better answer than your own you should up-vote it and consider to accept it instead of your own. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Absolutely!

I [do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93334/how-do-i-make-quickly-apps-install-into-opt) [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82322/how-do-i-fix-broken-networking-in-cloned-virtual-machines) [all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60712/how-do-i-quickly-encrypt-a-file-with-aes) [the](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40732/how-do-i-get-spaces-instead-of-tabs-in-nano) [time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33528/how-do-i-write-raw-bytes-to-a-sound-device) ;-) Somebody's bound to get some use out of it.

- If you have a good question, ask it.
- If you know an answer to a question, answer it.
- Ergo: if you have a good question and you know the answer, ask and answer it. :-)

If I type a question into google and I find the answer on AU, I don't really mind who wrote it. And that's what the site is for. So, out of habit, I nearly always "+2" these self-documentation questions.

Furthermore, if your question is even slightly interesting, there's a good chance you'll get additional answers on it, which means more information available to everyone.

In fact, on the [Stackoverflow Blog it is stated that](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

> To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own
>   question, it is explicitly encouraged.

Comment: Thank you very much Stefano! I was really concerned about being flagged as somebody who just wants to increase his own Reputation points.

Comment: @Agmenor While people do get accused of that, thats mostly by the poor sports who don't really understand how the site works. :)

Answer (score 14):

Just a follow up since this won't fit in a comment, but I've been using AU as a sort of "personal documentation system" for when I am trying to do something and the information on the net is bad and I want to make sure that it's available to people and in a place where it can be peer reviewed:

Pre-write your answer ahead of time so that you can post it right away after you post your question. I've posted a question and then started writing my answer and I find that people start trying to answer the question right away! So then I feel bad that people were going off trying to find an answer that I already knew, so what I do is post the question and answer right away as soon as I can so that I don't waste someone else's time trying to fix something I already know but haven't written up yet.